# two thousand five hundred a year?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is sentence from novel 'the Death of the heart'

> From the business, and from interest on the residue of his mother's
>   capital, Thomas derived, at present, an income of **about two thousand
>   five hundred a year**.

The novel's time period is 1930s in London.
I thought two thoudand five hundred means £2500...
But that is so little as a year income + interest...
Thomas is rich busniessman.
Is that money is big money that time or I misunderstood the amount of money?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be answered by checking historical inflation rates, such as [this table that suggests £2500 in 1930 would be more than £150000 today](http://inflation.iamkate.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understood the number correctly.  Two thousand five hundred is 2500. However, you're not taking into account [inflation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation) (or some similar concept). Well, I don't know much about that, but I Googled it and [this site](http://www.in2013dollars.com/1930-GBP-in-2017?amount=2500) tells me

> In other words, £2,500 in 1930 is equivalent in purchasing power to £155,293.35 in 2017, a difference of £152,793.35 over 87 years.

In today's currency, the number looks more significant.

Comment: That amount of money was a good salary for an office worker in 1970, forty years later.